# editing table using vba

Tags: c, vba, excel

I'm trying to edit the following table (the left one in the picture): I have columns of x, y, test name, pass/fail (0 if pass and 1 if fail), and "firstFAIL" column.
For each pair of x and y I have to check what is the first fail test and update the "firstFAIL" column as you can see in the picture:
[image: table]

I wrote a code using c language but I don't know how to run it on the excel file or how to write it in VBA.
My code is:

```
    for(i == 1; i <= 28; i += 14){      
         for(j == 1; j <= 14; j++){         
               if(PASS_FAIL[i * j] == 1){       
                    for(k == 1; k <= 14; k++){      
                          firstFAIL[k] == Test[i * j];
                    }
               break;
               }
         }
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions? 
Thank you all!

Comment: I didn't the logoc behind how the get from the picture on the left to the picture on the right, expand your explanation of the code logic.

Comment: @Alex, the column of "PASS_FAIL" determinds if the test pass (0) or not (1). for each couple (x,y) I want to check what is the first failure, for example for (122,125) the first test that fail was "e" test so in the column of the "firstFAIL" for all of the rows of (122,125) it has to be writen.